# How to access window or document object in nodejs /es2017

Tags: node.js, typescript, dom, ecmascript-2017

I'm trying to access document.getElementbyID and document.location in my typescript application. But getting error.

(node:3024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: document is not defined

NB: Please note that I don't want to use jquery so that it will reduce my bundle size.

Any other replacement of jquery in node is also acceptable with less size

Answer (score 0):

Actually, nodejs code don't run on browser. Its server side scripting language so there is no window or document object. If you still want to use document.getElementbyID. you can use "puppeteer".

**Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control headless Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. It can also be configured to use full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromiu**

Example,

1. `npm install puppeteer`
2. Added below code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function async xyz() {
   const browserData = await puppeteer.launch();
   page = await browserData.newPage();
   await page.goto('http://example.com/some.html', {waitUntil: 'load'});

const xyzPage = await page.evaluate(() => {
     return document.getElementById("xyzid").innerHTML;
});

console.log(xyzPage);

}
```

Note: there are another npm packages available that provide access to document object like JSDOM, etc. But lots of people are using "puppeteer".